# Difference in utility of cap/floor and FRA

Tags: interest-rates, derivatives, credit-derivatives, accrued-interest

What is the difference in utility for cap/floor and FRA? To me their function looks very similar. Are they used for different objectives. One thing I know in difference is that the pay off for cap is paid at the end of the term and for FRA the pay-off is calculated at the end but paid at beginning of the term with discounting incorporated. Please advise if I am wrong anywhere

Comment: A FRA is used to fix a future interest rate at a particular level. A cap is used to make sure a future interest rate does not exceed a particular level. For example, you could use a FRA to fix your borrowing rate in a years time to be 2.5%. If the realised rate in a year is 3% the FRA will pay you 0.5%. If the realised rate 2%, you will need to pay 0.5%. The cap can be used to cap your rate at 2.5%. If the realised rate is 3% the cap will also pay you 0.5% but if the realised rate is 2% you will not need to pay anything (so you can borrow at 2%). Clearly the cap costs more because of this!

Comment: Okay so the FRA is like a combination of a cap and a floor at the same rate?

Comment: A FRA is equivalent to buying a cap and selling a floor at the same rate (this is called [put-call parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity)).

Comment: Another thing you can say is Caps and Floors provide one sided hedging of interest rates, FRA provides complete (two sided) hedging.